# How to ignore CVS keyword tags in eclipse diff

Tags: eclipse, cvs

As much as i like the eclipse diff/merge perspective, when dealing with large projects and multiple branches that need to be merged occasionally there's one feature missing:

Is there any way to set the eclipse diff to ignore the CVS tags like *$Author:$*, *$Revision:$* and so on?

Since these tags are different in all the branches, a "compare to another branch" always results in a few hundred files showing up with differing tags but no apparent differences in the code. (of course tags differ only after fixing a bug in a few hundred files in branch and head. but that happens a lot where i'm working. no comments on that please.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=36436).

Comment: I was waiting for a workaround answer. But *sigh* yours is the only correct one as it seems.

Comment: Sigh indeed. Almost 10 years since it was reported and still not sorted. Wouldn't be so bad if there was a decent work around or something, but as it stands the compare view is totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, using keyword expansion with your SCM might be considered outdated procedure. [here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/keyword-substitution-just-say-no) are some compelling arguments.

Comment: Yes, it does cause problems. But on the other hand when you're juggling a few thousand files, it occasionally helps to know what version of a file you are talking about. That moment usually comes when your versioning system chokes because someone deleted or moved the CVS meta info folders around.